# How to find $y''_{tt}$?

Tags: derivatives

Let us have function $y(x)$ and $x = \varphi(t)$. Then parametric derivative should be:
$$y'_x = \dfrac{y'_t}{x'_t},$$
From where
$$y'_t = y'_x \cdot x'_t = y'_x \cdot \varphi'(t).$$

The parametric derivative of the second order should be:
$$y''_{xx} = (y'_x)'_x = \dfrac{(y'_x)'_t}{x'_t} = \dfrac{\left(\dfrac{y'_t}{x'_t}\right)'_t}{x'_t} = \dfrac{\dfrac{y''_{tt} \cdot x'_t - y'_t \cdot x''_{tt}}{(x'_t)^2}}{x'_t} = \dfrac{y''_{tt} \cdot x'_t - y'_t \cdot x''_{tt}}{(x'_t)^3},$$
From where
$$y''_{tt} = \dfrac{y''_{xx} \cdot (x'_t)^3 +  y'_t \cdot x''_{tt}}{x'_t} = \dfrac{y''_{xx} \cdot (\varphi'(t))^3 +  y'_t \cdot \varphi''(t)}{\varphi'(t)}.$$

Is it correct? If not, what should I do to get $y''_{tt}$?

Comment: Andrew, what you wrote is correct.

Comment: @Angelo thank you very much.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2631672/can-i-use-chain-rule-for-2nd-derivative also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724686/leibniz-notation-second-derivative-chain-rule and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3000015/chain-rule-of-a-second-derivative

Comment: @GerryMyerson ok, thank you